# How do I check what version of SunONE I am running?

Tags: sun-one

As the post states, how do I check what version of SunONE I am running?

This is on an IBM P5, AIX 5.3 system.

Comment: Are you referring to the web server, ldap, or something else?

Comment: My appologies, the web server.

Answer (score 1):

One simple way is to look at the error log. When the server is restarted, its precise version is displayed in the first log lines.

Answer (score 0):

I found some documentation that through our vendor that pointed to the correct path to find the information.  Unfortanely, it's a path that's pointing to the our application server and starts a the root.